# Why is this processing.js code not displaying in firefox?

Tags: processing

```html
<html>
<body>
<script src="processing.js"></script>
<script type="text/processing" data-processing-target="mycanvas">

Table table;
void setup() {
  table = new Table();
  table.addColumn("name");
  table.addColumn("type");
  TableRow newRow = table.addRow();
  newRow.setString("name", "Lion");
  newRow.setString("type", "Mammal");
  newRow = table.addRow();
  newRow.setString("name", "Snake");
  newRow.setString("type", "Reptile");
  newRow = table.addRow();
  newRow.setString("name", "Mosquito");
  newRow.setString("type", "Insect");

  println(table.getStringColumn("name"));
}
</script>
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is this code not displaying in Firefox? It should print all values in the column "name". This example is directly from the processing.js website.

Comment: Where on the website did you get this? Do you see any errors in the JavaScript console?

Answer (score 1):

Processing.js has no implementation of the newer Processing `Table` class, so it won't be doing very much unless you supply your own Processing implementation of the Table class (as additional file to load, for instance).

The currently supported API can be found on http://processingjs.org/reference/