# Using Processing's loadTable in javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, datatables, processing, processing.js

I have been working on a processing file, where I load in .csv data through the
`table = loadTable("testfile.csv", "header");`
method. 
All works fine and Dandy, until I try to export the processing file to javascript to run it in my browser. It seems that loadTable() isn't supported by javascript and results in the following error (Chrome):

"Uncaught ReferenceError: loadTable is not defined"

Is there any way to load .csv files into javascript, or a work around to use processing programs using tables in html?

Comment: This might be of use: http://papaparse.com/

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you've said it all: Processing.js has not yet implemented the `Table` class or the `loadTable()` function. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018055/why-is-this-processing-js-code-not-displaying-in-firefox) has an answer from a Processing.js developer confirming this.

You've got 4 options:

- Wait for [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) to catch up to Processing 3. I have no idea how long this will take. There was a link to an experimental version [here](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/11928/javascript-mode-removed), but I have no idea how stable that is.
- Implement the logic yourself. How big of a job this is depends on exactly what you're trying to do.
- Switch to [P5.js](http://p5js.org/), which has implemented the [`loadTable()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadTable) function. You'll have to change all of your syntax to JavaScript though.
- Don't deploy as a webapp. You can use Processing 3 and deploy as a runnable jar or an executable.